# Or in Refine fails?

Tags: refine

I think this should be `True`:

```
In[142]:= Refine[a^n\[Element]Reals,a\[Element]Reals&&n\[Element]Integers&&(a!=0||n>0)]
Out[142]= a^n\[Element]\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]
```

[image: Screen copy]

Where is my mistake?

Another example, correct:

```
In[150]:= Refine[a^-1\[Element]Reals,a>0||a<0]
Out[150]= True
```

[image: Screen copy]

I am using version 13.0.1.

Comment: The following suggests your title may be right in this particular case: `Refine[a^n \[Element] Reals, #] & /@ (a \[Element] Reals && n \[Element] Integers && (a != 0 || n > 0) // LogicalExpand)`

Comment: @MichaelE2 is right of course. Further supporting evidence. Both `Refine[a^n ∈ Reals, 
 a ∈ Reals && n ∈ Integers && a != 0]` and `Refine[a^n ∈ Reals, 
 a ∈ Reals && n ∈ Integers && n > 0]` yield `True`

Comment: `LogicalExpand` is a good idea but does not improve the case.  So it may be a bug.